# How to properly include Java sources in Maven?

Tags: maven, gwt

I'm working on a very simple blog engine in Java in order to learn multiple technologies.

Tech: Spring IoC, Hibernate, jUnit, GWT, and Maven.

I created two Maven projects: a core project and a GWT project (which has a reference on the core one)

Code is accessible at https://github.com/LaurentT/BlogEngineCore

My goal is the following: I want to include Java sources and XML since my GWT project is going to need the Java sources to compile it into JavaScript.

I tried to use the following code in the `<build>` element:

```xml
     <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.java</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.*xml</include>
                <include>**/*.*properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

My jUnit tests used to pass and finish before that add but now they are not even finishing they are hanging...

I have no clue what's going on, so I want to know if there are other ways to include Java sources or if I'm just doing it wrong.

Any clue?

Comment: why do you think "junit tests are hanging" has anything to do with including java sources?

Comment: It's just that if I remove those lines my tests are finishing and passing. I don't know why but that's what it is doing :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven create jar file with both .class and .java files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264359/maven-create-jar-file-with-both-class-and-java-files)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try including the ${basedir} in front of the directory path.

```xml
<resource>
    <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java</directory>
</resource>
```

Comment: Sean's solution was good if I wanted to have two separate JARs but here since my GWT project is loading one jar (the core project) I really need one JAR to be loaded in the classpath where I can find my sources. This worked like a charm! thanks a lot Mike

Comment: This will include all files in your source dir. While you probably want to include only `*.gwt.xml` and sources from `client` and `shared` dirs.

Answer (score 25):

The cleaner maven way would be to attach a separate source jar.

There are standard ways to generate it in your build [using the maven source plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/usage.html):

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>attach-sources</id>
      <phase>verify</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

And your GWT project can now reference your core project sources in addition to your core project jar:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>your.project</groupId>
  <artifactId>core</artifactId>
  <version>the.same.version</version>
  <classifier>sources</classifier>
  <scope>provided</scope><!-- use for compilation only -->
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Any way to do this in one jar only? Or is not a problem?

Comment: @LaurentT look atthe other answers for that. But as I said, that's less maven-like

Comment: Does this answer include `*.gwt.xml` files?

Comment: Separate jar for sources seems much better. Is there some reason why are GWT jars using mixed jars? And actually every 3rd party GWT module I know about?

Answer (score 3):

You can find how to setup maven for multimodule project [here](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/multiproject.html).

Where's the *gwt.xml file?

If the  tag shown is part of the *core* project's `pom.xml` file, then you should also add  `<include>**/*.gwt.xml</include>`:

```xml
<resource>
        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.java</include>
            <include>**/*.gwt.xml</include>
        </includes>
</resource>
```

Comment: This worked for me, however be careful, this will cause everything in src/main/resources to NOT be included in the jar. fix that simply by copying this and adding another resources for src/main/resources, including the appropriate extensions / wildcards

Comment: This example includes only the files required for gwt module, which is better than include blindly everything in src dir. Thanks!

Comment: @ClickUpvote you're right, the example was edited to make it more portable. It is drop-in now imho.

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to the other answers, my approach copies all `*.gwt.xml` module descriptors and only the java source files that are actually specified in the module descriptors. You also don't need to repeat yourself in POM and module descriptors.

**Update your pom with:**

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

**and your *.gwt.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module>

    <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code -->
    <source path='shared' />

</module>
```

**org:codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin docs**

> gwt:resources
>   Description: Copy GWT java source code and module descriptor as resources  in the build outputDirectory. Alternative to declaring a `<resource>` in the POM with finer filtering as the module descriptor is read to detect sources to be copied.
>   Implementation: org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.GwtResourcesMojo
>   Language: java
>   Bound to phase: process-resources