# How to generate a war file using relative link source folder

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have created a maven project in eclipse and took the java classes from another folder. I have chosen the **create links in work space** option instead of import. But while generating the war file maven is not including the java files. How to build a project with source links in maven?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this question:

[How to properly include Java sources in Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730168/how-to-properly-include-java-sources-in-maven)

This is helpful information in above post:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>attach-sources</id>
      <phase>verify</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```