# JAR file is corrupted

Tags: maven, jar, artifactory, bintray, jcenter

Why do i get this error when i'm trying to include my version inside JCenter from the JFrog interface:

```
JAR file is corrupted.A binary file (jar, aar, wat, apk) should be part of the package.Could not validate jar file.Package should include sources as part of the package.
```

Here is my package: 
https://bintray.com/dakarinternational/dakar/dakar#files/com/dakar/dakar

Sources and javadoc is already genereated and pushed on JFrog.
Localy, everything is working fine (java -jar ...)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to include the sources inside the main JAR not aside...

I did that by changing my build config in my pom.xml like explained in here: 
[include source inside the main jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23933911/include-source-code-while-exporting-a-jar-using-maven)