# How to build only java files with maven?

Tags: java, maven

i have  my project hierarchy like below

```
 myProject--->POM.xml
 myProject--->src--->main--->java---> java files under different sub directories
 myProject--->src--->main--->resources---> non java files under different sub directories
 myProject--->src--->main--->webApp---> non java files under different sub directories
```

i want to build the project so that it builds only java files and only include the corresponding class files in final jar file

Here is my relevant code from pom.xml but it does not find any java files to compile. I am not sure what i am missing here?

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
            <plugin> 
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId> 
              <configuration> 
                <verbose>true</verbose> 
                  <includes>
                            <include>**/*.java</include>
                            </includes>
              </configuration> 
            </plugin> 
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
</build>
```

**UPDATE:-** I get info message as
 `No sources to compile` but there are java file in subdirectories

Comment: Why would the jar plugin include .java files? Those are the source files. Did you mean *.class? Also, why would you not include the resources in your war?

Comment: yes you are right. Corrected my post

Comment: What's the configuration for your maven-compiler-plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you want to get rid of files like `.xml`, `.xhtml`, `.properties` etc?
Try to add

```
 <resources/>
```

Or you can disable the executions, see here:

[How to speed up Maven builds by 30 %: Supressing unused plugin executions](https://community.jboss.org/people/ozizka/blog/2013/07/06/how-to-speed-up-maven-builds-disabling-unused-plugins)

Suppress the `resource:default-resources` and `war:default-war` executions.

Actually you'll have to, because the `war` plugin doesn't obey `<resources>`.

Still, the `jar` plugin will add `META-INF` dir. That can be deleted before the `package` phase using the `clean` plugin.

Check [this page](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) for further studies.

Comment: i want to get rid of all files(not only resources) except java files

Comment: can you tell me where to add  <resources/> under build tag in pom.xml

Comment: Check this: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html

Answer (score 0):

You can add resources for your java files under the build like this:

```
<build>
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/java</directory>
  </resource>     
</resources>
```

Also you may need to put your java files into your output directory. And remove the includes.

Comment: it includes everything like property, js, xsr files in jar. So it does not work

Comment: I found a possible copy at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916091/adding-java-source-java-files-to-test-jar-in-maven

Comment: you need to move your java files to output directory. Use maven-ant-plugin to copy the files