# Maven - How do I create source jar for test package?

Tags: java, maven

I have a Maven project called `my-work` which has two source directories 
`src/test/java` and `src/main/java`. I needed to convert both of them into one JAR file so that other projects could use them, but I ended up converting them into two separate JARs. Now, I need to be able to create source JARs for each of these two JARs.

I first created two JARs from `main/` and `test/` directories by adding this to my `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then, I tried the instructions [here](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/generate-source-code-jar-for-maven-based-project/) to make sources JARs. The problem is that it only creates one source JAR i.e. `my-work-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar`. But, I want it to also create `my-work-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-tests-sources.jar`. How do I do that?

Here is the full POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-work</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <build>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <!--etc-->
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <name>mywork</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!--Dependencies here-->
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Consider moving the tests into a separate project. You have most likely reached the point where maven gets cumbersome.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - Can I do it without moving tests into a separate project ? Other projects need to access classes from both main and test directories of my-work jars. Some classes of test directory in turn access main classes.

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/test-jar-mojo.html

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - Thanks. Could you please suggest a tutorial which shows how to make a sources jar for the test jar also ?

Comment: Have you tried with maven profiles?

Comment: @SHoko - No. Could you please tell me more about how it can help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: Sorry, meant separate Maven module, not project.  That allows you to keep the classes in the same project even if split in two modules.  Regarding how to create a jar from your test classes, see the provided link.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To generate both standard source and test source JARs, use the following plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>test-jar</goal>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Note that this will not generate a test JAR (only a standard JAR). To generate both a standard and test JAR, you can use the following plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>test-jar</goal>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 6):

I am able to generate sources for test with help of below plugin. can you post your pom file ?

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
 </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks. The code creates my-work-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-tests-sources.jar. How can I make it also create my-work-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar ? I want two source jars to be created, one for the main package and the other for the test package.

Comment: I added the pom in the question.

Comment: You just need to add <goal>jar</goal> to maven source plugin. You can upvote my answer if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest looking at the plugin doco for that goal

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/test-jar-mojo.html

It looks like the test-jar goal uses the default manifest file, which would explain why the sources are combined into the same jar file.

My suggestion is to use the defaultManifestFile setting to point to a new manifest file.  You will need to define this file yourself, but then you can ensure that the target jar is given a distinct name, thus making it a different JAR file.

Hope this helps

Comment: I added the full pom file in the question now. Could you please show me how I can update the pom to give me the two jars ?